# How to close all IDE "New Edit Windows" (some of which are not visible)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Recently in the D7 IDE, I started using the "New Edit Window" option.

Now, it seems that I have several non-visible edit windows, because sometimes the title bar for a particular window will have the filename followed by a colon and number, as shown below.

This can be confusing, since sometimes use File, Open to open a .pas file and nothing seems to happen, because, I suspect the code is already in an open (but hidden) windows.

I've tried closing all the windows I can see, etc, but these title bars with a number following the filename keep re-appearing, sometimes floating over other editing windows.

Is there a surefire way to close all edit windows so I'm back to just having one?

[image: Title bar showing :#]

**Additional information in response to comments:**

I am able to close the individual files (tabs) in window with the standard  Ctrl-F4. And when the last file is closed, the window disappears as it should. But sometimes when I open a new file, it opens in a new editing window (as if I'd actually clicked on the "New Edit Window" option in the context menu.)  It appears that there are several windows that were created by "New Edit Window" commands that are hidden and sometimes are used to display newly opened files.

Comment: -1?  Really, you've got to be kidding? At least show your reason or vote to close.

Comment: Can you select the edit window with the Window menu and then press Ctrl+F4?

Comment: Can be done with a key press in modern delphi ide

Comment: @Robert: I didn't downvote, but at SO there is no requirement to explain why you downvote a question, so demanding that someone do so isn't going to work. Voting here is anonymous for several reasons (such as people wanting to get revenge, flame wars, etc.). Some people leave a comment explaining why, but there is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cause:

This is due to the Autosave Editor files option in the environment settings.

When this is enabled, windows that aren't explicitly closed within the project session are indeed *remembered* by that option. Although, there really are no *hidden* windows, just the count of previously created windows is stored.

#### Solution:

Delete the corresponding Delphi Desktop File (*.dsk) from the project folder, or manually edit that file and rewrite `EditWindowCount=4` to `EditWindowCount=1` within the `[Modules]` section.